# Clipping a range of values in matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I have a 2D numpy array called img that I plot using imshow as shown below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

//some calculation to calculate 2D array img
plt.imshow(img, vmin = -1000, vmax = 1000)
plt.show()
```

The img array by default has values from -2000 to 2000 and I use vmin and vmax to clip the plot between -1000 and 1000. I was wondering if there is a similar way to NOT plot values from -100 to 100 but plot every other value between -1000 and 1000  (i.e, plot x where -1000 < x < -100 or 100 < x < 1000 )

Thanks.

Comment: You would need a `for` loop based function to do that.

Comment: Don't use a for loop! Apart, I'm not sure it is clear what output you'd expect. Do you simply want to leave those points transparent? In that case you can mask the array (see numpy.ma).